# Levi-Civita symbol in 2-spinor notation

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, spinors

I'm reading *An Introduction to Twistor Theory*, by Huggett and Tod, and I don’t get the result we're being given page 17: the 2-spinor form of the 4 dimensional Levi-Civita symbol.
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{abcd} = i (\epsilon_{AC}\epsilon_{BD}\epsilon_{A'D'}\epsilon_{B'C'}-\epsilon_{AD}\epsilon_{BC}\epsilon_{A'C'}\epsilon_{B'D'}) 
\end{equation}
To get to this expression, we are supposed to write $\epsilon_{ABCDA'B'C'D'}$ as a sum of symmetric and antisymmetric spinors. The explanation is to just apply repeatedly the procedure shown on the previous page on the spinor equivalent of a valence 2 tensor. But I don't understand how to write this sum. I tried two different things :

1. (anti)Symmetrising on only two indices at a time :

$\epsilon_{ABCDA'B'C'D'} = \epsilon_{(AB)CDA'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{[AB]CDA'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{AB(CD)A'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{AB[CD]A'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{A(BC)DA'B'C'D'}  +\epsilon_{A[BC]DA'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{(DA)BCA'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{[DA]BCA'B'C'D'}$

And then following on the rest. I already see two problems : there's going to be a term in $\epsilon_{AB}$, which there isn't in the final expression. Secondly, I should probably add a factor looking like $\frac{1}{n}$ (no idea what $n$ should be equal to though)

2. (anti)Symmetrising over every (un)primed at indices at once:

$\epsilon_{ABCDA'B'C'D'} = \epsilon_{(ABCD)A'B'C'D'} + \epsilon_{[ABCDA]'B'C'D'} $

This isn't even correct, I detailed everything and didn't find $\epsilon_{ABCDA'B'C'D'}$ again.

So here are my questions: a) what is exactly meant by applying the procedure repeatedly?

b) Where does the $i$ come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using the two component spinor conventions of [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750305061) book, since I'm not familiar with your reference. There are two methods I can think of that should work, then you can adapt them to your notation.

We want to simplify the following expression as much as possible
$$\epsilon_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}\beta\dot{\beta}\gamma\dot{\gamma}\delta\dot{\delta}}:= (\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}(\sigma^c)_{\gamma\dot{\gamma}}(\sigma^d)_{\delta\dot{\delta}}\epsilon_{abcd} \tag{1}$$

**Method one**

As a first step rewrite it as follows

$$ \epsilon_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}\beta\dot{\beta}\gamma\dot{\gamma}\delta\dot{\delta}}=-\text{i}(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}(\sigma^c)_{\gamma\dot{\gamma}}\big(\sigma_a\tilde{\sigma}_b\sigma_c-\eta_{ac}\sigma_{b}+\eta_{bc}\sigma_{a}+\eta_{ab}\sigma_{c}\big)_{\delta\dot{\delta}} \tag{2}$$
where I have made use of the identity
$$\sigma_a\tilde{\sigma}_b\sigma_c=\eta_{ac}\sigma_{b}-\eta_{bc}\sigma_{a}-\eta_{ab}\sigma_{c}+\text{i}\epsilon_{abcd}\sigma^d~.$$
Then just use the identity
$$(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma_a)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}=-2\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}$$
repetitively to simplify the right hand side of (2).

**Method two**

First split the sigma matrices in (1) into two sets of pairs and try to convert each into double sigma matrices $$\sigma^{ab}:=-\frac{1}{4}\big(\sigma^a\tilde{\sigma}^b-\sigma^b\tilde{\sigma}^c\big)~,\qquad \tilde{\sigma}^{ab}:=-\frac{1}{4}\big(\tilde{\sigma}^a\sigma^b-\tilde{\sigma}^b\sigma^c\big)~.$$
I'll do it explicitly for one pair (I wont write the other two sigma's for ease of notation):
\begin{align}
(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}\epsilon_{abcd}&=\big((\sigma^a)_{(\alpha|\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{|\beta)\dot{\beta}}+(\sigma^a)_{[\alpha|\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{|\beta]\dot{\beta}}\big)\epsilon_{abcd} \tag{3}
\end{align}
Term one: Due to the antisymmetry in $(a,b)$ and the symmetry in $(\alpha,\beta)$, the two indices $(\dot{\alpha},\dot{\beta})$ are antisymmetric. Any rank-2 spinor $F_{\alpha\beta}$ which is antisymmetric $F_{\alpha\beta}=-F_{\beta\alpha}$, is proportional to the spinor metric with the half the trace as proportionality constant: $F_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}F^{\delta}{}_{\delta}$. Implementing  this observation on (3) we get
\begin{align}
(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}\epsilon_{abcd}
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}(\sigma^a)_{(\alpha}{}^{\dot{\delta}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta)\dot{\delta}}+\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma^a)^{\delta}{}_{(\dot{\alpha}|}(\sigma^b)_{\delta|\dot{\beta})}\Big)\epsilon_{abcd} \\
&=\Big(\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\big(\sigma^{ab}\big)_{\alpha\beta}-\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}\big(\tilde{\sigma}^{ab}\big)_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\Big)\epsilon_{abcd}
\end{align}
Then do the same thing for the other two sigma matrices in (1). Next we use the (anti-)self duality properties of the double sigma matrices:
$$ 
\frac{1}{2}\big(\sigma^{ab}\big)\epsilon_{abcd}=-\text{i}\sigma_{cd}~, \qquad \frac{1}{2}\big(\tilde{\sigma}^{ab}\big)\epsilon_{abcd}=\text{i}\tilde{\sigma}_{cd}~. 
$$
To finish it off, you will need the following identities
$$
\big(\sigma^{ab}\big)_{\alpha\beta}\big(\sigma_{ab}\big)_{\gamma\delta}=-2\varepsilon_{\alpha(\gamma}\varepsilon_{\delta)\beta}~,\qquad \big(\sigma^{ab}\big)_{\alpha\beta}\big(\tilde{\sigma}_{ab}\big)_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}=0~,\qquad \big(\tilde{\sigma}^{ab}\big)_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\big(\tilde{\sigma}_{ab}\big)_{\dot{\gamma}\dot{\delta}}=2\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}(\dot{\gamma}}\varepsilon_{\dot{\delta})\dot{\beta}}~.
$$

Comment: thank you. However, I'm still having difficulties with the methods you described. I posted my (new) questions as a separate answer for ease of formatting. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Sure I will take a look when I get some free time, I have been busy lately. Regarding your first question though, you should use the identity
$$(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma_a)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}=-2\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}\varepsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}.$$

Comment: Just note that the first term can be written as
$$(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}(\sigma^c)_{\gamma\dot{\gamma}}\big(\sigma_a\tilde{\sigma}_b\sigma_c\big)_{\delta\dot{\delta}}=(\sigma^a)_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}(\sigma^b)_{\beta\dot{\beta}}(\sigma^c)_{\gamma\dot{\gamma}}(\sigma_a)_{\delta\dot{\mu}}(\tilde{\sigma}_b)^{\dot{\mu}\mu}(\sigma_c)_{\mu\dot{\delta}}$$